# Update to 12.04 failed, now unusable system

Tags: 12.04, installation, updates

During the installation it mention something about sandbox or something like that.
But it continued normally. The installation was interrupted twice by a message that said only 500mb are free, delete some applications, etc. I pressed the option that would have allowed me to do that but never actually opened until the end of the installation were a message announce a mistake that made impossible to finish the process, said the system might be unusable and that a recovery stuff would start but that never happened.
I can open some programs like this one and libre office but can not start the software center and the update manager.
I've considered downloading the OS from Internet to a CD and reinstall but I know I'll lose all my applications, and documents, I made a backup before so my files are safe but I don't want to install all my apps again.
Is there any other way?
Thanks for any help or advice you can give me.

Comment: Software index is broken

It is impossible to install or remove any software. Please use the package manager "Synaptic" or run "sudo apt-get install -f" in a terminal to fix this issue at first.
When I open the Update manager a message like this one appears.

Comment: Please open a terminal then and proceed as the answer suggests -- DO NOT keep trying with Update Manager.

Answer (score 2):

> but I don't want to install all my apps again. Is there any other way?

**You have no free space.** That's why your upgrade failed and you are stuck in an "unusable" state. Please delete files to free up some space -- you can start by deleting the files you already have a backup of -- at least 1-1.5GB is recommended.

Once that's done, open Terminal `Ctrl-Alt-T` and run `sudo apt-get install -f`. That may give you errors; if it does, try resuming the upgrade with `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Sometimes this won't work either because the system thinks you have upgraded to 12.04 but you are, in fact, stuck half-way. You can do this then:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup
sudo sed -i -e 's/precise/oneiric/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

with a `sudo apt-get install -f` if that is recommended by apt-get/dpkg.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problem.  [Please see my post on ubuntuforums.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2074094)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.